# Powershell WPF ComboBox to update ListBox

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, combobox, listbox

I have a ComboBox that doesn't quite work.
It has 3 static selections for essentially sorting a long list of connection profiles plus a 'Select One' which is automatically selected.

No matter what selection I choose, nothing happens until I click on another selection. Now this is the interesting part. No matter what I choose next, the listbox populates with my previous selection.

```
<ComboBox Name="CBox" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <ComboBoxItem Name="cbSelect" IsSelected="True">Select Profile</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="cbRemote">Remote</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="cbLab">Lab</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="cbTomcats">Tomcats</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
<ListBox Name="ListBox" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />


$syncHash.CBox.Add_SelectionChanged({
    If($syncHash.CBox.Text -eq "Select Profile")
    {
        $syncHash.ListBox.Items.Clear()
    }
    If($syncHash.CBox.Text -eq "Remote")
    {
        $syncHash.ListBox.Items.Clear()
        $profiles = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
        $profiles = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Profiles")
        foreach ($profile in $profiles)
        {
            if ($profile -match 'Remote \-')
            {
                [void]$syncHash.ListBox.Items.Add($profile.BaseName)
            }
        }
    }
    If($syncHash.CBox.Text -eq "Lab")
    {
        $syncHash.ListBox.Items.Clear()
        $profiles = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
        $profiles = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Profiles")
        foreach ($profile in $profiles)
        {
            if ($profile -match 'Lab \-')
            {
                [void]$syncHash.ListBox.Items.Add($profile.BaseName)
            }
        }
    }
    If($syncHash.CBox.SelectedItem -eq "Tomcats")
    {
        $syncHash.ListBox.Items.Clear()
        $profiles = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
        $profiles = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Profiles")
        foreach ($profile in $profiles)
        {
            if ($profile -match 'Tomcats \-')
            {
                [void]$syncHash.ListBox.Items.Add($profile.BaseName)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Final Solution using Rohin Sidharth's answer:

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll'
$Global:syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})

[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="ComboBox Test" Height="500" Width="350">
    <Grid Width="340" Height="470">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
            <RowDefinition Height="0.1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.9*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>            
        <ComboBox Name="CBox" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <ComboBoxItem Name="cbSelect" IsSelected="True">Select Profile</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Name="cbRemote">Remote</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Name="cbLab">Lab</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Name="cbTomcats">Tomcats</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <ListBox Name="ListBox" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@
    $reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
    $syncHash.Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
    [xml]$XAML = $xaml
    $xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'Name')]]") | %{
        $syncHash.Add($_.Name,$syncHash.Window.FindName($_.Name) )
    }
function Get-Profiles
{
    $profiles = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Profiles")

    $syncHash.ListBox.Items.Clear()

    If ($syncHash.CBox.SelectedIndex -eq 1)
    {
        foreach ($profile in $profiles)
        {
            if ($profile -match 'Remote \-')
            {
                $syncHash.ListBox.Items.Add($profile.BaseName)
            }
        }
    }
    ElseIf ($syncHash.CBox.SelectedIndex -eq 2)
    {
        foreach ($profile in $profiles)
        {
            if ($profile -match 'Lab \-')
            {
                $syncHash.ListBox.Items.Add($profile.BaseName)
            }
        }
    }
    ElseIf ($syncHash.CBox.SelectedIndex -eq 3)
    {
        foreach ($profile in $profiles)
        {
            if ($profile -match 'Tomcats \-')
            {
                $syncHash.ListBox.Items.Add($profile.BaseName)
            }
        }
    }
}

$syncHash.CBox.Add_SelectionChanged({Get-Profiles})

$null = $syncHash.Window.ShowDialog()
$syncHash.Error = $Error
$Error
```

Comment: I haven't quite worked with WPF in powershell but in Winforms, I think to select an item on the combobox, you have to set the SelectedIndex property and not the text of the item. An index of 0 will select the 1st item on your dropdownlist.

Comment: Genius!This worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am gonna add it as answer so you can properly appreciate me...lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't quite worked with WPF in powershell but in Winforms, I think to select an item on the combobox, you have to set the `SelectedIndex` property and not the text of the item. An index of 0 will select the 1st item on your dropdownlist